# Converting pool timer box to smart wi-fi sytem

Tags: electrical

I have a timer box going to my pool. Not sure whether its 115 or 240. I want to take off the timer box and install a regular receptacle to plug the motor into. Using smart Wi-Fi Outdoor plug.
thx

Comment: We're going to need  few pictures of the inside of the timer box and the circuit breakers feeding it.

Comment: Can you post photos of the equipment in question please?

Comment: More details are required in order to provide a quality answer. If you have a multi-meter, you should measure the voltage, or at least look at the breaker in the disconnect to see if its a single or double.